# How to find the Column Name of a Table from its Column Value in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, view, inner-join

I have a view which returns a result as follows:

```
     D1      D2      D3      D1_CODE       D2_CODE      D3_CODE
    ----    ----    ----    ---------     ---------    ---------
   10.00    13.00   14.00      OD           LENGTH     THICKNESS
```

I created the view on the below selection query,

```
    SELECT 
        MKT_MRL_Detail.D1,
        MKT_MRL_Detail.D2,
        MKT_MRL_Detail.D3,
        MAS_SizeType.D1_Code,
        MAS_SizeType.D2_Code,
        MAS_SizeType.D3_Code
FROM
        MKT_MRL_Detail INNER JOIN
        STR_Item ON STR_Item.ItemID = MKT_MRL_Detail.ItemID INNER JOIN
        MAS_SizeType ON MAS_SizeType.SizeTypeID = STR_Item.SizeTypeID
```

I have return the view Based on the Inner Join of Two Tables.
The above view returns only one row. Here, I want to find which Column has a value 'LENGTH':
I am using SQL Server 2005. Can any one please help?

Comment: You don't have access to view the contents of the view?!  In management studio, right click the view name & select `edit`.

Comment: ya ok. Dont consider it as a View. Please Consider it as a selection based on inner join of the two tables. In that case can we find?

Comment: Hi Ponies: I edited my question please have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best suggestion would be to re-write the view (or possibly even the database) since this is not a very good design.  However, I doubt that is possible.  If it is not, here is my suggestion:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT D1 AS Value, D1_CODE AS Code
FROM view
UNION ALL
SELECT D2, D2_CODE
FROM view
UNION ALL
SELECT D3, D3_CODE
FROM view
) AS myInfo
WHERE Code='LENGTH'
```

It isn't pretty but it would get the job done.

Comment: I would also test putting the WHERE statement inside each select statement. It it simpler where it is but if you ever decide to return lots of records instead of one, it will perform better. However, in this case the performance difference does not warrant doing so.

Comment: OK Biggs. But your first solution is very apt to my Problem.